# CNN network, continue using conv2d, without using maxpool, a question from reading the keras book

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm reading the learning with Python book from Francois Chollet. On page 128, the author is discussing the problem of having continuous Conv2d layer instead of having a maxpooling layer. My question is from the following paragraph. **I don't get where 7X7 come from?**

> It isn’t conducive to learning a spatial hierarchy of features. The 3 × 3 windows
>   in the third layer will only contain information coming from 7 × 7 windows in
>   the initial input. The high-level patterns learned by the convnet will still be very
>   small with regard to the initial input, which may not be enough to learn to classify
>   digits (try recognizing a digit by only looking at it through windows that are
>   7 × 7 pixels!). We need the features from the last convolution layer to contain
>   information about the totality of the input.

```
Layer (type) Output Shape Param #
================================================================
conv2d_4 (Conv2D) (None, 26, 26, 32) 320
________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D) (None, 24, 24, 64) 18496
________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D) (None, 22, 22, 64) 36928
================================================================
Total params: 55,744
Trainable params: 55,744
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Kindly do not edit back - this is the standard SO format for *quoted* passages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that your cnn architecture only has 3*3 kernels.

Thanks to a 3*3 kernel, the first layer is creating features map from your input. Each pixel of these feature maps are only dependant on a 3*3 square of the input. Than the second layer is doing the exact same thing, taking the feature maps as input. So now, one pixel is dependant on a 3*3 square of a feature map, which is dependant on a 5*5 square of the input.

By doing that a third time, a pixel on a third layer feature map only depends on a 7*7 window of the input.

Here is a 1D example :

```
        *            # third layer pixel
      | | |
      * * *          # second layer pixels
    | | | | |
    * * * * *        # first layer pixels
  | | | | | | |
  * * * * * * *      # input pixels --> An unique third layer layer pixel depends on only 7 input pixels
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pierre!!! Your graph very illustratively answered the question!!!

Comment: @Pierre-Nicolas Piquin, Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Can you please explain how this problem is fixed using Max Pooling. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm reading the book in this moment and had the exact same question, great explanation!